# Widgets in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

G'day :)

I'm building a website for a Bed & Breakfast and need to integrate it with a channel manager (handles bookings and other things).

The channel manager provides a widget, but it is written in jQuery. Here is a link to the documentation (it's not long):

http://gadgets.securetravelpayments.com/_doc/

I can include the widget in an iframe, but this seems like taking major steps backward and the returned theme doesn't fit with Material 2.

Here is a link that returns an actual page for my client's B&B:

http://book.resonline.com.au/make-booking?ap=415569

Included on request is some code that I've tried so far (there's not much to see):

```
<md-card>
    <iframe frameborder="0" (load)="onload($event)" 
        src="https://book.resonline.com.au/make-booking?ap=415569">
    </iframe>
</md-card>

export class BookingComponent {
    element: HTMLFrameElement;

    onload(event: Event) {
        this.element = <HTMLFrameElement> event.srcElement;
        this.element.height = 
        this.element.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide what you have tried

Comment: I have edited and added the code that I have used in terms of setting up the widget in an iFrame, but to keep going with this it looks like I'll have to deal with a CORS issue.

Comment: So the issue is that the styling of the frame doesn't match your website? Becuase you can't penetrate an iframe with css.